Kafka - Getting error - Error checking or creating metrics topic
Trying to install confluent platform 7.5.3 - Kafka on 6 nodes and see below messages in server.log
Getting error -   Error checking or creating metrics topic (io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter) org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException:
 Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: describeTopics

I get this error while trying to create topic. Not sure what is wrong, what should be the configurations I should be looking at ?
Also now, when I look at /var/log/messages, I see
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ClusterAuthorizationException: Request UPDATE_METADATA is not authorized.

